# MySQL query: selecting latest results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySQL table with data, and would like to select the most recent entry for a specific test that was conducted.

```
table: research
columns: id (int), projectid (int), test (varchar),
         when (datetime), result (longtext)
```

Example of rows:

```
1, 6, "Test1", 01-01-2013 12:15, "AAAAA"
2, 6, "Test1", 01-01-2013 13:15, "BBBBB"
3, 6, "Test2", 01-01-2013 16:00, "CCCCC"
4, 6, "Test2", 01-01-2013 16:15, "DDDDD"
5, 6, "Test2", 01-01-2013 16:30, "EEEEE"
```

If I want the latest results for "Test 1", I use..

```
SELECT *
FROM research
WHERE projectid=6 AND test='Test1'
ORDER BY when DESC limit 1
```

But how can I get the latest result for each test in a single project, in one query? I tried:

```
SELECT research.*
FROM research INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
                          FROM research
                          WHERE projectid=".$ProjectId."
                          GROUP BY test) ids
     ON research.id = ids.id
WHERE research.projectid=".$ProjectId
```

But it does not give me the latest result from a test, it gives me the oldest..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the subquery is that it separately gets the latest date `WHEN` for every projectid and test. The result of which is then joined back on the original table.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    research a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT projectid, test, MAX(`when`) maxDate
            FROM research
            GROUP BY projectid, test
        ) b ON  a.projectid = b.projectid AND
                a.test = b.test AND
                a.`when` = b.maxDate
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfc65/1)

Comment: I think you forgot to select a specific projectid in this query? (no where clause) If so, where would that go?

Comment: the query illustrate the latest record for all projectid and test, if you want for specific projectid, you can all `WHERE a.projectid = 6`

Comment: adding that to the end of the query works indeed. I tried this query and it works!! Thank you a lot!

Comment: PS: I added "AND a.projectid=$ProjectID" to the end instead of WHERE, and it works? Should be no problem right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `WHERE` with `IN` that filters on the `max(when)` date:

```
select *
from research r
where r.projectid = 6
   and r.`when` in (select max(`when`)
                   from research
                   group by projectid, test);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfc65/15)

Comment: Much like remigio and including projectid-selection. Well done! Works and is relatively small compared to JW. Perhaps someone knows why the difference matters in his and yours..

Comment: @JaredNinja In SQL there are always a variety of ways to get a result. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT test,when,result
FROM research r1
WHERE when = (SELECT max(when)
            FROM research r2
            WHERE r2.test=r1.test)
```

Comment: Works when you enclose when like: \`when\` (interesting, since this query is much smaller). Yet, you forgot the projectid selection.

Answer (score 0):

So, to get for every test of every project, the row with the largest `when` column, you can use this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM research AS r 
  JOIN
    ( SELECT projectid, test, MAX(`when`) AS maxw
      FROM research
      GROUP BY projectid, test
    ) AS m
    ON  m.projectid = r.projectid
    AND m.test = r.test
    AND m.maxw = r.`when` ;
```

---

For every test of a single  project (say project `6`):

```
SELECT r.*
FROM research AS r 
  JOIN
    ( SELECT test, MAX(`when`) AS maxw
      FROM research
      WHERE projectid = 6
      GROUP BY test
    ) AS m
    ON  m.test = r.test
    AND m.maxw = r.`when` 
WHERE r.projectid = 6 ;
```

An index on `(projectid, test, when)` will help efficiency of both the above queries.

---

Comment: This looks much alike JW., haven't tested it though since JW. was first and his solution worked. But thanks for the effort ypercube!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the query below.

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM (
SELECT `r`.*
FROM research `r`
ORDER By `r`.`when`
DESC
)`e`
WHERE `e`.`projectid`= $ProjectId GROUP BY `e`.`test`
```

I Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont know why it got -1, when its a good and simple option.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it's probably because this is based on undocumented behaviour.

Comment: Well thanks for the advice, I will keep that in mind next time :)

Comment: Discussion here: [What corner cases exist when relying on undocumented behaviour to determine values selected by MySQL for hidden columns in GROUP BY operations?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28913/what-corner-cases-exist-when-relying-on-undocumented-behaviour-to-determine-valu)

Comment: I did not down-vote (cant even, too few rep) but your code works. For me though, its barely readable compared to others.

Answer (score 0):

Partition by test and order by date within the partition. Use analytic functions. No need for complicated queries above/below...